# Streamlit button positioning

Tags: python, html, css, streamlit

I am new to python and streamlit. I have created a button using streamlit, which i positioned at center of page using st.columns. after clicking that button, i use request get some data and published it on st.text prompt . Problem is changing position button to col2 text prompt width becomes small as col2 width only, and starts from center. If i change it to col1 , than it start from left,as i want but width column is still small, how to destroy column, thing after button positioning.
Note: I also want to create one download button at center below of text prompt, so will create cols again.

```
st.title("Downloader")
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a Java file", type="java" , accept_multiple_files=False)
    col1, col2, col3 = st.columns([1, 2,3])
    code = "" 
    #check if file is uploaded or not
    if uploaded_file is not None:
        fileDetails = {"Name":uploaded_file.name,"Size":uploaded_file.size}
        st.write("Uploaded file details:" )
        
        try:
            code = str(uploaded_file.read(),encoding="utf-8")
            
        except Exception as e:
            st.error(f'failed to read java file :{e}')
    if code:
        with col2:
            if st.button("Generate"):
                t=request.post(url)
                st.text(t)
                col1, col2, col3 = st.columns([1, 2,3])
                with col2:
                      st.download_button('d',t)
```